Inductive and projective limit of circles
This post concerns the calculation of an inductive limit and a projective limit in $\mathsf{Top}$. My questions are as follows:

Is it true that in $\mathsf{Top}$, we have the following?
$$
\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}}
\operatorname{colim} \left( S^1 \overset{\times 2}{\twoheadrightarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 3}{\twoheadrightarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 4}{\twoheadrightarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 5}{\twoheadrightarrow} \ldots \right) \cong \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Q}}
$$

Is my proposed calculation of the inductive limit correct? In particular, in which categories do we need to consider the limits / colimits to make it meaningful?

Is it true that in $\mathsf{Top}$, we have the following?
$$
\operatorname{lim} \left( S^1 \overset{\times 2}{\twoheadleftarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 3}{\twoheadleftarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 4}{\twoheadleftarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 5}{\twoheadleftarrow} \ldots \right) \cong \mathbb{R}
$$

Is my proposed calculation of the projective limit correct? In particular, in which categories do we need to consider the limits / colimits to make it meaningful?


Here's my attempt to calculate the inductive limit:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
& \operatorname{colim} \left( S^1 \overset{\times 2}{\twoheadrightarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 3}{\twoheadrightarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 4}{\twoheadrightarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 5}{\twoheadrightarrow} \ldots \right) \\
\cong & \operatorname{colim} \left( \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\times 2}{\twoheadrightarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\times 3}{\twoheadrightarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\times 4}{\twoheadrightarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\times 5}{\twoheadrightarrow} \ldots \right) \\
\cong & \operatorname{colim} \left( \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\frac{1}{3!} \mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\frac{1}{4!} \mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow} \ldots \right) \\
\cong & \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\operatorname{colim} \left( \mathbb{Z} \overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z} \overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} \frac{1}{3!} \mathbb{Z} \overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} \frac{1}{4!} \mathbb{Z} \overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} \ldots \right) } \\
\cong & \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{ \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n!} \mathbb{Z} } \\
\cong & \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Q}} \\
\end{array}
$$
Next, here is my attempt to calculate the projective limit:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
& \operatorname{lim} \left( S^1 \overset{\times 2}{\twoheadleftarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 3}{\twoheadleftarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 4}{\twoheadleftarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 5}{\twoheadleftarrow} \ldots \right) \\
\cong & \operatorname{lim} \left( \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\times 2}{\twoheadleftarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\times 3}{\twoheadleftarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\times 4}{\twoheadleftarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\times 5}{\twoheadleftarrow} \ldots \right) \\
\cong & \operatorname{lim} \left( \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadleftarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{2 \mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadleftarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{3! \mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadleftarrow} \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{4! \mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadleftarrow} \ldots \right) \\
\cong & \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\operatorname{lim} \left( \mathbb{Z} \overset{\iota}{\hookleftarrow} 2 \mathbb{Z} \overset{\iota}{\hookleftarrow} 3! \mathbb{Z} \overset{\iota}{\hookleftarrow} 4! \mathbb{Z} \overset{\iota}{\hookleftarrow} \ldots \right) } \\
\cong & \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{ \bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n! \mathbb{Z} } \\
\cong & \quotient{\mathbb{R}}{\{0\}} \\
\cong & \mathbb{R} \\
\end{array}
$$
Edit: I just noticed that my calculation of the projective limit cannot be correct, since a projective limit of compact Hausdorff spaces is again compact Hausdorff. The question is then what this projective limit actually is.

I think when you write $S^1\cong \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ you're saying something true but as topological groups (and you sneak this characterization in, when interpreting the diagram arrows as quotient maps). Also, to be super-formal, you should make precise in what sense $\mathbb R/(-)$ is a colimit-preserving functor, in order to deduce the third isomorphism.

@fosco Thanks, I think actually that's pretty much what I'm unsure about. In what categories do I need to work in to make this precise?

What are the maps $\times 2$, $\times 3$, etc?

@PatrickR Viewing $S^1$ as an additive topological group, it's multiplication by $2$, $3$, etc.

Topologically, it's a degree $2$, $3$, etc. map

We should work in the category $\mathbf{TopAb}$ of topological abelian groups.
The first calculation is correct. But it can be generalized a lot:
Let us first ignore the topology. Let $A$ be any abelian group. Using that the functor $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} - : \mathbf{Ab} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ preserves colimits and maps $\mathbb{Z} \mapsto A$, there is an isomorphism
$$\mathrm{colim}(A \xrightarrow{2} A \xrightarrow{3} \dotsc) \cong A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathrm{colim}(\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{3} \dotsc).$$
The colimit on the right is equal to the colimit of the chain of subgroups
$$\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} \mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \dotsc,$$
which is just $\mathbb{Q}$. So the result is $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$. For $A = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ this is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$.
Now, assume that $A$ is a topological abelian group. Instead of working with the tensor product, which may be a bit hard to topologize, we may work with the localization. Specifically, we look at the topological abelian group $(\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\})^{-1} A$ defined by the obvious universal property in $\mathbf{TopAb}$. A slick construction (which also works in the discrete setting) is to take the filtered colimit of the diagram
$$(\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\},\, \mid \,) \mapsto \mathbf{TopAb}$$
that sends $z$ to a copy of $A$, and a relation $z \mid z'$ to the morphism $\frac{z'}{z} : A \to A$. Basically, we may see the copy of $A$ at $z$ as a formal version of $\frac{1}{z} \cdot A$ here.
Notice that $A \mapsto (\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\})^{-1} A$ preserves colimits since colimits commute with colimits. Next, we use that
$$(\mathbb{N},\leq) \to (\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\},\,\mid\,), \quad n \mapsto n!$$
is a cofinal map (since $z$ divides $n!$ where $n := |z|$). Hence, the colimit is the same as the colimit of the diagram restricted to $\mathbb{N}$, meaning
$$(\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\})^{-1} A \cong \mathrm{colim}(A \xrightarrow{2} A \xrightarrow{3} \dotsc)$$
in $\mathbf{TopAb}$. So in that category we compute
$$\begin{align*}\mathrm{colim}(S^1 \xrightarrow{2} S^1 \xrightarrow{3} \dotsc) & \cong (\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\})^{-1} S^1 \\ & \cong  (\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\})^{-1} (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) \\ & \cong (\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\})^{-1} \mathbb{R} ~ / ~ (\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\})^{-1} \mathbb{Z} \\ & \cong \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}.\end{align*}$$
Your second calculation is not correct where you exchange the colimit (quotient) with the limit. This can only be done in very special cases. But we may apply analoguous arguments to check
$$\mathrm{lim}(A \xleftarrow{2} A \xleftarrow{3} \dotsc) \cong \hom(\mathbb{Q},A)$$
for $A \in \mathbf{TopAb}$, where $\hom(\mathbb{Q},A)$ is a topological subgroup of the power $A^{\mathbb{Q}}$. (But I cannot say right now if this helps to determine this group for $A=S^1$.)

By the "obvious universal property" of $(\mathbb{Z} \setminus {0})^{-1} A$, you mean that for any topological abelian group $B$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus {0}$ multiplication by $n$ is an automorphism of $B$, all continuous group homomorphisms $A \to B$ factor uniquely through $A \to (\mathbb{Z} \setminus {0})^{-1} A$?

Why do we have $(\mathbb{Z} \setminus {0})^{-1} \left( {^{\Large \mathbb{R}}}/{{\Large \mathbb{Z}}} \right) \cong {^{\Large (\mathbb{Z} \setminus {0})^{-1} \mathbb{R}}}/{{\Large (\mathbb{Z} \setminus {0})^{-1} \mathbb{Z}}}$?

$\operatorname{hom}(\mathbb{Q}, A)$ is endowed with the subspace topology coming from the product topology of $A^{\mathbb{Q}}$, yes? Why isn't it the compact-open topology?

First question: yes. Second question: colimits are preserved by the localization as mentioned. 3) Why should it have the compact-open topology? The topology on Q is obviously irrelevant here.

Thanks. Can you explain how localization preserving colimits implies localization distributing over quotients?

Quotients are colimits (cokernels).

$(\mathbb{Z} \setminus {0})^{-1}$ is the left adjoint to the inclusion of topological $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces in topological abelian groups, right? This should be another way to see that it preserves colimits.

Yes but you have to be careful here, I do not mean vector spaces over the topological field $\mathbb{Q}$! The action doesn't have to be continuous (I think).

As mentioned, that the localization preserves colimits is simply because it is built out of colimits, and colimits commute with colimits. $$\mathrm{colim}_i S^{-1} A_i = \mathrm{colim}_i \mathrm{colim}_s A_i = \mathrm{colim}_s \mathrm{colim}_i A_i = S^{-1} \mathrm{colim}_i A_i$$

The projection maps from $\operatorname{hom}(\mathbb{Q}, A)$ to the $A$'s in $\operatorname{lim} (A \overset{\times 2}{\leftarrow} A \overset{\times 3}{\leftarrow} A \overset{\times 4}{\leftarrow} \ldots)$ are the evaluation maps at $1$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3!}$, etc., right?

That's right. $~~~~$

Your projective limit is the pushout $P$ of the following diagram of topological abelian groups:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc} \mathbb{Z}&\to&\mathbb{R}\\ \downarrow&& 
\stackrel{:}{\vee}
\\ \hat{\mathbb{Z}}&\dashrightarrow&P \end{array}
$$
where $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the profinite completion of the integers and the arrows are the natural inclusions. In particular, you have natural quotient maps $P\to P/n!\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{R}/n!\mathbb{Z}$, to each circle in your sequence. Notice how the topology of the pushout (with standard topology on $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$) corresponds exactly to the preimages of open subsets of the circles.
The inclusion of $\mathbb{R}$ in $P$, on the right hand side of the above diagram shows how your answer sits inside the full answer $P$.
Finally, as a sanity check, let's show that $P$ is compact: $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is compact, $[0,1]$ is compact, and $P$ is a quotient of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}\times [0,1]$ by the relation $(n,0)\sim (n-1,1)$.

Proof that $P$ satisfies the universal property of the projective limit of: $${\mathbb{R}}/{\mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadleftarrow} {\mathbb{R}}/{2 \mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadleftarrow} {\mathbb{R}}/{3! \mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadleftarrow} {\mathbb{R}}/{4! \mathbb{Z}} \overset{\pi}{\twoheadleftarrow} \ldots $$
Let $A$ be a topological abelian group, and let $f_n\colon A\to \mathbb{R}/n!\mathbb{Z}$ be maps commuting with the maps $\pi$ (which all map real numbers to themselves).
For any $a\in A$, we have a sequence of residues $f_n(a)\in\mathbb{R}/n!\mathbb{Z}$.  As they are coherent, they will coincide with a unique $p_a\in P$. That is we can pick $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\subset P$ to represent $f_0(a)\in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, and for $n>0$ we can pick an integer $r_n$ such that $f_n(a)=\alpha+r_n\in \mathbb{R}/n!\mathbb{Z}$.  Further, as the congruence of $r_n$ modulo $k!$ remains fixed for $n>k$, there is a unique $r\in \hat{\mathbb{Z}}\subset P$ which agrees with $r_n$ modulo $n!$ for all $n$.  Thus $p_a=\alpha+r$ is the unique element of $P$ which maps to $f_n(a)$ for all $n$.  Note if instead of $\alpha$ we had picked $\alpha+k$ for some integer $k$, then the element of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ which we would have attained is $r-k$, so we would still have $p_a=\alpha+k+r-k=\alpha+r$.
Thus the only map $A\to P$ which makes the diagram commute is the one sending each $a\mapsto p_a$.  Let $h$ denote this map.  It remains to show that $h$ is continuous.
The open sets in $P$ are generated by the premimages of open sets in $\mathbb{R}/n!\mathbb{Z}$ under the maps $P\to P/n!\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{R}/n!\mathbb{Z}$.  Thus the preimage of such an open set under $h$ is generated by the preimages of open sets under the $f_n$, which are open as the $f_n$ are continuous.

Thanks for the answer. Is it really the pushout in the category of topological groups? Why not in the category of topological abelian groups? Can you give a proof?

You are right of course, I did not mean the amalgamated free product!  I have edited "abelian" in.

I have added a proof at the end.

Nice description! In the proof, "For any $a\in A$, we have a sequence of residues $f_n(a)\in\mathbb{R}/n!\mathbb{Z}$.  As they are coherent, they will coincide with a unique $p_a\in P$." is not complete I would say.

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you.  I have added a few lines of explanation.
